# Append text to first occurrence of a pattern using sed

Tags: unix, shell, shell-script, sed

Say there is a text file as below:

```
Hello world
types=""
Mario
types="Game"
```

What I want to do is find the first occurrence of `type=""` and append with word "program". I need output as:

```
Hello world
types="program"
Mario
types="Game"
```

I need to use this in Unix shell scripting. What I tried is:

```
sed -i '1,/types=""/s/types=""/types="program"/' filename
```

As the command looks, it's inserting only, not appending. I tried adding `a\` but it's still not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `sed` one-liner substitution seems to already work as you intend:

```
$ cat t.txt
Hello world
types=""
Mario
types="Game"

$ sed '1,/types=""/s/types=""/types="program"/' t.txt

Hello world
types="program"
Mario
types="Game"
```

It might be worth editing your question to show what *you* get when you run your `sed` command (without the `-i` option so that the results are printed to the terminal).

BTW, your range of `1,/types=""/` is redundant. You can simplify it as:

```
sed '/types=""/s/types=""/types="program"/' t.txt
```